# How do we know that these roots are non-real?

Tags: roots, quadratics

The roots, x and y, of a quadratic equation $$ax^2 + bx + c=0$$ satisfy the following inequality:

$$x^2 + y^2 < 0$$

What can you conclude about the nature of the roots of the quadratic equation?

---

$$x^2 + y^2 = (x+y)^2 - 2xy = \frac{b^2 - 2ac}{a^2}$$

since $$x^2 + y^2 <0$$, we can say $$b^2 - 2ac < a^2$$
therefore, $$b^2 - 4ac < a(a-2c)$$
therefore,$$ D < a(a-2c)$$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Please note that you should use [MathJax codes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make questions and answers more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively:
$$x^2+y^2=\left(\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}<0 \Rightarrow$$
$$b^2-4ac<0 \Rightarrow x,y\in \mathbb{C}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2 + y^2<0$, they can't be real because squares of real numbers are non-negative.

Comment: Thanks, got it. :)

Comment: Since $x^2+y^2\lt0$ they can't **both** be real. If we further assume that $a,\ b,\ c$ are real (that wasn't given in the question), then $x$ and $y$ are complex conjugates, so **both** are non-real.

Comment: @bof That is true, although it takes a special kind of complex quadratic equation to make $x^2 + y^2$ real. Real coefficients are a particularily simple subset of those.